# need help to understand on below oracle code

Tags: sql, oracle, object

I came across some oracle snippet. Can anyone explain it and what the code returns?

I tried google to find out what does odciobjectlist and did not get correct explanation.

```
Select ID,Objectname Name 
from table(SYS.odciObjectlist(SYS.OdciObject('1'.'Appr'),SYS.ODCIObject('2','Pending')))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`odciObjectlist` is one of several Oracle owned types, which we can use for building our own extensions to Oracle. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADDCI/ext_types_ref.htm#ADDCI4190)

Specifically `SYS.odciObjectlist` is an array of type `SYS.odciObject`, which is intended to store information about a schema object - schema name, object name. However, the constructor is fairly forgiving and we can use `odciObject` to store pairs of any string.

In the case of your query, it looks like somebody is instantiating a collection of (?) statuses (?) which are rendered as a queryable table using the `table()` function. It's a cheap way of generating a result set on the fly, rather than using some selects from dual and UNION ALL.

With `table()` we can take any SQL nested table collection and query it in the FROM clause of a SELECT, with a result set which has one row for each object in the collection. So if we take the query posted in your question and fix the grammar like this ...

```
Select objectschema as id
      ,objectname   as name
from table(SYS.odciObjectlist(
                SYS.OdciObject('1','Appr')
               ,SYS.OdciObject('2','Pending')
                             )
          )
```

...the output we get is:

```
ID   NAME                                                                                                                              
---- ---------------------------------------------------------
1    Appr                                                                                                                              
2    Pending
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Could you please provide me some samples or examples for a better understanding of how it provides output

Comment: @Jyo - [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) has some explanation of table collection expressions and collection unnesting, which is what is happening here.